# How can I make a table that can collapse its rows into categories in Qt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a table in Qt that can collapse and expand its rows into groups (the rows are grouped by the content of a specific column), such as this:

**All groups expanded:**

[image: Rows expanded]

**First group collapsed:**

[image: Rows collapsed]

When clicking on the "group header rows", all "child rows" are either collapsed into the "group header row" or shown underneath it.
The table should also be able to "un-group" itself and become a normal table.

I've tried using a QTreeView with QTableWidget as child widgets, but then it becomes a problem to "un-group" the tables into a single table.

I also tried using QTableView and adding the "group header rows" to the table. It sort of works, but it has been very tough to implement it correctly, since it involves moving rows around and inserting these "fake rows" that behave very differently the rest, thus messing up the underlying QStandardItemModel. It also makes sorting unreasonably complicated.

Is there any better way to implement this kind of widget, or maybe there already exists a standard Qt widget that implements this functionality? I reckon I can eventually make it work with my current QTableView with "fake rows" (maybe), but so far it has been so prone to breaking and hard to implement that I really want a better solution...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, a QTreeView should be used as shown in the following example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

datas = {
    "Category 1": [
        ("New Game 2", "Playnite", "", "", "Never", "Not Played", ""),
        ("New Game 3", "Playnite", "", "", "Never", "Not Played", ""),
    ],
    "No Category": [
        ("New Game", "Playnite", "", "", "Never", "Not Plated", ""),
    ]
}

class GroupDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GroupDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self._plus_icon = QtGui.QIcon("plus.png")
        self._minus_icon = QtGui.QIcon("minus.png")

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(GroupDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        if not index.parent().isValid():
            is_open = bool(option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open)
            option.features |= QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDecoration
            option.icon = self._minus_icon if is_open else self._plus_icon

class GroupView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(GroupView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        delegate = GroupDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
        self.setModel(model)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #0D1225;")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_clicked(self, index):
        if not index.parent().isValid() and index.column() == 0:
            self.setExpanded(index, not self.isExpanded(index))


class GroupModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GroupModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(8)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["", "Name", "Library", "Release Date", "Genre(s)", "Last Played", "Time Played", ""])
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            it = self.horizontalHeaderItem(i)
            it.setForeground(QtGui.QColor("#F2F2F2"))

    def add_group(self, group_name):
        item_root = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item_root.setEditable(False)
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(group_name)
        item.setEditable(False)
        ii = self.invisibleRootItem()
        i = ii.rowCount()
        for j, it in enumerate((item_root, item)):
            ii.setChild(i, j, it)
            ii.setEditable(False)
        for j in range(self.columnCount()):
            it = ii.child(i, j)
            if it is None:
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                ii.setChild(i, j, it)
            it.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#002842"))
            it.setForeground(QtGui.QColor("#F2F2F2"))
        return item_root

    def append_element_to_group(self, group_item, texts):
        j = group_item.rowCount()
        item_icon = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item_icon.setEditable(False)
        item_icon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("game.png"))
        item_icon.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#0D1225"))
        group_item.setChild(j, 0, item_icon)
        for i, text in enumerate(texts):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            item.setEditable(False)
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#0D1225"))
            item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor("#F2F2F2"))
            group_item.setChild(j, i+1, item)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        model = GroupModel(self)
        tree_view = GroupView(model)
        self.setCentralWidget(tree_view)

        for group, childrens in datas.items():
            group_item = model.add_group(group)
            for children in childrens:
                model.append_element_to_group(group_item, children)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(720, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Knowing that QStandardItem can have children makes a lot of difference. Using a QTreeView that way seems pratical. I made some tests and it seems that this approach will work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @drakenation QStandardItemModel is a base, you could implement your own model, but my object is to show you that the best option of the view is to use QTreeView. I could create a model that inherits from QAbstractItemModel since clearly the structure is from a tree where the parent nodes are the category types and the child nodes are the items that belong to the category :-)